# Symfony route /{slug} overriding existing routes

Tags: symfony, url, routes

I have the entity `Page` identified by slug. Also I have the action to view a page in the Page controler :

```
/**
 * @Route("/{slug}", name="app.page", requirements={"slug": "[\w-]+"})
 * @ParamConverter("page", class="AppBundle:Page", options={"slug" = "slug"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Page $page
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function showAction(Request $request, Page $page)
{
    // replace this example code with whatever you need
    return $this->render('Page/view.html.twig', array(
        'page' => $page,
    ));
}
```

I am trying to get pages from the database, well this works. But I have a problem, all the existing routes (ex : /login) is overriden by this action so instead of viewing the login form I get 404 as I don't have  page with the slug login in the DB.

How to force Symfony to use this route if there isn't any matching route defined ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your main routing file ( found in your config folder ) - just change the order of your bundle references.
Whichever route gets matched first is the one the router will use so its possible to change which order they are checked.

Simply place your PageController bundle at the very bottom.

You can also reference controllers seperatly in the routing file if you have multiple controllers within the same bundle

Answer (score 1):

Yes or so you can use prefixes for your URL does not look like too.
For example :
`/page/{url}` or `/user/login`
Best is to choose the order of declaration of the routes. But sometimes it can cause little troubles if your urls are simmilar...